# How can I capture the URL which a user first visits in my Angular application

Tags: angular

I am trying to capture the url that a user of my website first visits and use the query params for analytics purposes.

I have an Auth guard set up which protects some routes and redirects users to the `/login` route.
In my app-component.ts, I have the following code

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe((params) => {
        if (params.myparam) {
          // do stuff here with myparam
        }
      });

  }
```

If a user were to visit the url http://localhost:4200/someurl which is protected by my guard, how can I evaluate the url before the guard has ran, to capture the url. I have added the code above in the ngOnInit of my app-component.ts file however this only executes after the guard has finished, by this point it has redirected me to the login screen, and now from my analytics point of view, it looks like the user landed on the login screen rather than the page 'someurl'

Comment: Have you considered putting your code to execute in the guard?

Comment: Good idea, yes I have however not all routes have the guard applied, but I need to capture the first visited url, regardless of the route, so this is not an option

Comment: Gotcha. Is the expectation that people will be accessing whatever route directly in the browser? or will they be navigating to it from a routerLink within your Angular app?

Comment: Correct, they will be linked to unique pages externally (guarded or unguarded), if they have logged in to my site prior, then they will be shown the page they are trying to visit, if not then they will be redirected to login, then redirected back to the screen they are trying to visit

Comment: One approach would be to catch those URLs server-side via Angular Universal. I don't know what kind of work you need to do before the Angular route renders, but that will definitely give you the ability to catch the route before *any* Angular code executes.